# What is the simplest way to cook wheat flour with salt distributed through the wheat?

Tags: wheat

I only want to use 3 ingredients wheat flour, salt and water and I want to ensure the salt is distributed throughout the wheat and not just the surface. I also want to cook the simplest method.

Things like pasta would not work since salt only goes to the surface.

I imagine the answer is to make mix salt, water and wheat(i.e. make a dough) and the either make it into a dumpling or chapati by shaping it then microwaving, pan heating, grilling or baking it.  Would this be correct?

Can it be eaten raw?

Comment: Why would pasta not work ? you just add the salt whilst kneading the dough? (dissolve in water0

Answer (score 2):

You can first mix the salt into the water and and then form your dough with salted water.

For cooking. I’d recommend baking as when you’re boiling the dough such as in the case of noodles and/or dumpling you’ll eventually lose some of the salt to the cooking water.

Comment: does the dough need to be shaped into something thin like chapatis or can you just bake the whole block of dough then cut before serving? if so how long and at what temp should the block be cooked for?

Comment: I’d recommend a thin layer of dough, as it won’t have the leavening effect of yeast or baking soda.

Answer (score 1):

As you are saying nothing about ratios, you can simply mix all three together, making sure to use a sufficient amount of liquid and cook a kind of pudding or - if even thinner - [gruel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gruel). The salt would be able to dissolve completely and be evenly distributed. The basic principle can be applied to a wide selection of grains or seeds and is known in many cuisines around the world, e.g. congee made of rice.

Cooking *may* be optional (the FDA [warns](https://www.fda.gov/ForConsumers/ConsumerUpdates/ucm508450.htm) against eating raw flour, I could find no corresponding warning issued by the German or European food safety authorities). Whether it’s a culinary satisfying option, is for you to decide.

Comment: In the US we have had several instances of flour being recalled because of salmonella or E. coli contamination. It is generally considered risky nowadays to eat dough, batter, or cookie or cake mixes, etc. before they are cooked.

Comment: @Cindy did some research (thanks for the hint). It seems German and EU authorities see no particular risk, whereas the FDA has issued a warning. In any case of consuming unheated food there is a remaining minimal risk - salads and sprouts are probably way more risky foods than flour, I would assume.